# is there a way to improve the function that find a substring of a very large function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to run this code but this function indeed consumes more time. I want to improve this code:

```
def minion_game(string):
    k = 0
    s = 0

    for i in range(len(string)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(string) + 1):
            ss = string[i:j]
            if ss[0] in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']:
                k += 1
            else:
                s += 1

    if len(string) in range(0, 10 ** 6):
        if string.isupper():
            if k > s:
                print(f"Kevin {k}")
            if s > k:
                print(f"Stuart {s}")
            if k == s:
                print("Draw")
```

Comment: What exactly is your aim? What is your input and what is the output you expect? The logic to get to that output?

Comment: Why are you taking a slice `string[i:j]` and then only using the first character of the slice? You might as well skip the slice entirely and just check `string[i]`

Comment: ahh... i want to classify the sub_strings of that large string whether they start with vowels or not if they start with vowel kevin gets a point else stuart scores atlast i want to print their scores , ii have a very large string about 1000 letters im getting time limit error

Comment: even if there is a duplicate of substring they still gets a score

Comment: Can you provide a small example?  You used the string "BANANA" in a comment below. Can you walk through how exactly to count the scores for Kevin and Stuart? Maybe for a second word like "Yellow" as well. I think some people (like me) thought you were simply counting vowels.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Counter class is usually pretty efficient in a case like this. This should be mostly similar to what you have done in terms of results, but hopefully much quicker.

```
from collections import Counter

k_and_s = Counter('k' if c in 'AEIOU' else 's' for c in string)
k, s = k_and_s['k'], k_and_s['s']
if k > s:
    print(f'Kevin {k}')
elif k < s:
    print(f'Stuart {s}')
else
    print(f'Draw')
```

Zooming in on `k_and_s = Counter('k' if c in 'AEIOU' else 's' for c in string)`, this uses comprehension in place of a loop. It is roughly equivalent to this:

```
k_and_s = Counter()
for c in string:
    if c in 'AEIOU':
        k_and_s['k'] += 1
    else
        k_and_s['s'] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def minion_game(string):
    k = 0
    s = 0
    l = len(string) # save length in a variable
    for i in range(l):
        for j in range(i + 1, l + 1):
            ss = string[i] # take only the first
            if ss in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']:
                k += 1
            else:
                s += 1

    if l in range(0, 10 ** 6):
        if string.isupper():
            if k > s: # change from three if's to if, elif, else
                print(f"Kevin {k}")
            elif s > k:
                print(f"Stuart {s}")
            else:
                print("Draw")
```

I made a few edits that should speed up your code. They are described in comments on the lines. There seems to be some logic missing in the j-loop.
I'm not sure what you are doing on the line `if l in range(0, 10 ** 6):`. If you wanted to remove it, then it'd look like:

```py
def minion_game(string):
    k = 0
    s = 0
    l = len(string) # save length in a variable
    for i in range(l):
        for j in range(i + 1, l + 1):
            ss = string[i] # take only the first
            if ss in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']:
                k += 1
            else:
                s += 1
    
    # removed loop, which definitely saves time
    if string.isupper():
        if k > s: # change from thee if's to if, elif, else
            print(f"Kevin {k}")
        elif s > k:
            print(f"Stuart {s}")
        else:
            print("Draw")
```

Comment: There must be some logic missing, the j-for loop does nothing

Comment: The `10**6` line wasn't a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @jamie-deith is good and fast. It will process the complete works of Shakespeare in about 0.56 seconds on my computer. I gave up timing the original answer and modifications of it as it simply goes on and on.

This version is simple and produces the same answer in 0.26 seconds.  I'm sure them are likely even faster answers:

```
with open("shakespeare.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file_in:
    shakespeare = file_in.read().upper()

kevin = len([character for character in shakespeare if character in 'AEIOU'])
stuart = len(shakespeare) - kevin

if kevin > stuart:
    print(f'Kevin {kevin}')
elif kevin < stuart:
    print(f'Stuart {stuart}')
else:
    print(f'Draw')
```

Comment: i tried this but it always print draw for ex: BANANA

Comment: ahh... i want to classify the sub_strings of that large string whether they start with vowels or not if they start with vowel kevin gets a point else stuart scores atlast i want to print their scores , ii have a very large string about 1000 letters im getting time limit error

Answer (score 0):

Taking the (perhaps doubtful) position that your code is doing what you intend, but slowly, I note:

The amount added to `k` or `s` for any value of `i` depends on how many times we go around the `j` loop. You're repeatedly testing the character at `i` (with the same result every time of course) and adding one to either `s` or `k`, as many times as we go around the loop.

So we don't need to actually go around the `j` loop; we can just add that amount on a single test. For the first character you go the same number of times around the loop as the length of the string, then reducing by one as you shift along the string.

So we can lose `i` and iterate through the string characters directly.

Then finally we don't report anything if the string is too long or not upper case, so we can just do that test first, and not even calculate in those circumstances.

```
def minion_game(string):
    if len(string) < 10**6 and string.isupper():
        k = 0
        s = 0
        j = len(string)
        for ss in string:
            if ss in 'AEIOU':
                k += j
            else:
                s += j
            j -= 1 # reducing amount to add

        if k > s:
            print(f"Kevin {k}")
        elif s > k:
            print(f"Stuart {s}")
        else:
            print("Draw")
```

As a hint for even faster options, I'll note that `k+s` is constant depending on the length of the string.